# cordova & bootstrap in android resolution

Tags: android, cordova

I made cordova app with bootstrap4.

It's resolution work fine on almost smartphones.

but, this app has resolution problem that width is so small on  some smartphones.

I added viewport line like it.

How can I do someting?

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"

left picture is works fine version. right picture has problem.

[image: Screenshot is here]